# Difference between viewDidUnload and dealloc function when I release the Object

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I set a variable as IBOutlet.
and use `@property(retain)` `@synthesize` in my **.h** and **.m** file.
Like this:

```
@interface testViewController {

    NSArray *keys;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *keys;

@end

@implementation SectionViewController

@synthesize keys;
```

In many books, they set that object to nil in `viewDidUnload` method, and use release method to release that object in `dealloc` method.
Like this:

```
- (void)viewDidUnload {
    self.keys = nil;
}


- (void)dealloc {
    [super dealloc];
    [keys release];
}
```

As I know, if I use self.keys = nil, the result is same as `[keys release]` in `dealloc` method;Object keys will be `release`, and "nil" will not be retain.

Why some books use this form every time?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First off, your `-dealloc` method will crash. You've put the call to `[super dealloc]` in the wrong spot. Calling `[super dealloc]` will cause your object to be freed, so any references to ivars after this call are referencing garbage memory. Instead you should rewrite this to be

```
- (void)dealloc {
    [keys release];
    [super dealloc];
}
```

Now to answer your question. It seems you want to know why people say `self.keys = nil` in some places, but use `[keys release]` in dealloc. There's a few good reasons. The first is that someone (a coworker, your self a few months from now, or a user if you open-source your code) may override the setter `-setKeys:`, either in this class or in a subclass. That setter may make assumptions about the state of the object that simply aren't valid in `-dealloc` (e.g. assuming that other ivars/properties still contain valid values). If assumptions like this are made, then it simply isn't safe to call the setter in `-dealloc`. Another reason that's harder to track down is someone may have an active Key-Value Observing registration on your object, for the key `@"keys"`. Calling `self.keys = nil` will fire off a KVO notification, which is not something you want to do in dealloc. However, saying `[keys release]` will skip the KVO notification entirely.